# Selenium Python Action Move to doesn't work on hover element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, python

Hi I need to click hover element in **Selenium Python**.

I tried to use `action` chains and then move to element but it didn't work for me.

**My Selenium code Snippet:**

```
element1= self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#layout-center .ui-tabs-nav.ui-helper-reset.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-widget-header.ui-corner-all.ui-sortable")

element2=self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#layout-center button.add-widget")
ac(driver).move_to_element(element1).click(element2).perform()
```

In the picture you can see how it looks in html code.
[image: Button to click]

Comment: If you want hover, why you perform click?

Comment: element 2  is visible after hover on element 1. I used Actions Chains for move and click in Java and it was working good. Now I need solution i Python because on geckodriver 16.1 and selenium 3.42 it doesn't work.

Comment: Please determine "didn't work". Any errors? What is happening - do you see the "hover" part working? Thanks.

Comment: Using move to doesn't print any errors. The mouse cursor just didn't move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are trying to use `move_to_element`, which currently isn't supported in the marionette/gecko driver. You can track the implementation [on their GitHub](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/1653).

> moveTo is not part of the W3C WebDriver spec, it would be a good idea to move to the actions API to support modern firefox.

Comment: Any solution to make mouse over element 1 to click element 2?

Comment: Use Chrome or Python's gtk.gdk.Display class